# print in TextBox Tkinter Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, scrollview

I don't know what exactly what should I called this problem so if plz edit if not fully understand.
I am writing a program in Python on Ubuntu, to print file names in TextBox with scrolling option in Y-axis.

But file names are appearing outside the TextBox and scroll option is also not working properly.
I also attached the output of program below
[image]

Can you plz me to resolve this issue?

```
import io,sys,os,subprocess 
from Tkinter import *

def viewFile():
    s=1
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        var= StringVar()
        var.set(f)
        l1 = Label(mainframe, textvariable=var)
        l1.grid(row=s)
        s += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    mainframe= root.title("FILE MANAGER APPLICATION")                         # Program Objective
    mainframe= root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="File View",   font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 1, column =2)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 1, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("~/python")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `viewFile` function doesn't even refer to `tex`, so it makes sense that none of the filenames are going in the Text. If you don't want the filenames to appear as individual Labels, then don't call `Label`.

Comment: @Kevin so how do I mention it in 'tex'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert the filenames in `tex`, then call `tex.insert` instead of creating new Labels.

```
def viewFile():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        tex.insert(END, f + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. is that possible it only shows .h264 extension files?

Comment: Sure, you just need an `if f.endswith(".h264"):`.

Comment: Once again Thanks for your answer... Is it possible Can I make these file click-able ?